# Register-IoTDevice : The term 'Register-IoTDevice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management, azure-iot-hub-device-update

i'm getting the below error while registering the IoT Device via Powershell Command

Register-IoTDevice : The term 'Register-IoTDevice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:11

- $device = Register-IoTDevice @deviceParams
- ```
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Register-IoTDevice:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Install-Module -Name AzureIoT after adding this in Powershell ISE it's working

Comment: Add your comment as answer for the benefit of the community reading this thread which helps in finding the answers quickly.